# How to see code coverage of a tests in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

Does anyone know a way to get test code coverage  results when running CN1 tests?

I'd like to have an idea about the parts of the code that are not being exercised by any tests.

I'm using Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be able to use a plugin like [this one](http://wiki.netbeans.org/TutorialCodeCoveragePlugin) to enable coverage to the project then run the unit tests as you would run them normally. I haven't tested it myself but because a Codename One project is just a regular IDE project under the hood it should be possible.